# Writing a URL to an embed-field using PodioKit

Tags: objective-c, podio

I hope to find some help to diving deeper into Podiokit, the ObjC-API to Podio. I try to set a link-field's value to a URL. My first simple try looked like this:

```
NSDictionary *embedAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: @"http://www.google.com" forKey: @"url"];            
PKTEmbed *embed = [[PKTEmbed alloc] initWithDictionary: embedAttributes];
item[@"linkfield"] = embed;
```

I found an example using PHP but had no luck to transform it into Objective-C:

```
$attributes = array( 'url' => 'http://www.infranet.com' );
$embed = PodioEmbed::create( $attributes );
$attribute['embed']['embed\_id'] = $embed->embed\_id;
$attribute['file']['file\_id'] = $embed->files[0]->file\_id;
$this->orgItem->field('organizationlink')->set\_value($attribute);
```

Maybe someone knows how to get it right, would be fine :-)

[Edit] The PodioKit-Manual just says:

```
PKTEmbed *link = ...;
item[@"link"] = link;
```

[Edit 2] The error occurs when I try to save the item. The log says:

```
Error: Saving file Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: Ungültige Anforderung (400)" UserInfo=0x600000c7ee80 {com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x6000008358e0> { URL: https://api.podio.com/item/app/_xxxx_/ } { status code: 400, headers {
"Content-Length" = 263;
"Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
Date = "Sat, 27 Sep 2014 19:16:22 GMT";
Server = nginx;
"X-Podio-Request-Id" = yqyl6yku;
"X-Rate-Limit-Limit" = 250;
"X-Rate-Limit-Remaining" = 248;
} }, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: Ungültige Anforderung (400), NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.podio.com/item/app/_xxxx_/}
```

Thanks,
Michael / Hamburg

Comment: ummm... what errors are you getting? Where and what do you define `item` as? these things will help.

Comment: Item is defined earlier:

    PKTItem *item = [PKTItem itemForAppWithID:appId];

Comment: Setting values of other fields works without problems. I think the problem is get an accepted instance of PKTEmbed with an URL only...

Comment: After creating the PKTEmbed instance its embedId is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sebastian at Podio here. You need to first create the PKTEmbed object server side, then use it as the value of the item field. So you would use:

```
PKTItem *item = ...;
[[PKTEmbed createEmbedForURLString:@"https://www.google.com"] onSuccess:^(PKTEmbed *embed) {
  item[@"link-field"] = embed;
} onError:^(NSError *error) {
  // Handle error
}];
```

The server will assign you an embedID and generate a thumbnail for you etc. I will look into adding the ability to simply provide a URL string directly, as I agree that makes a lot of sense.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Wow, I did nearly a copy/paste of your code and it works perfectly!
Greetings from Germany/Hamburg!

Comment: I have now added the ability to give an `NSString` with the URL directly on object creation. Like `item["link-field"] = @"https://www.google.com"` You just need to run `pod update` to get the latest changes from the master branch. Hope that helps!

Comment: That's a good and clear improvement! I think it will help a lot when setting a link field's value, it's really more straight foreward :-) But the other way works, too!